# ->toArray() is giving empty arrays instead of objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a chunked array of 1000 Raw Objects:

```
class Raw extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'raws';
    protected $casts = [
        'time' => 'datetime'
    ];
    public $timestamps = [
        "time"
    ];
    private string $operationId;
    private string $meterId;
    private string $consoProd;
    private string $timestep;
    private string $unit;
    private string $timestamp;
    private string $value;
}

collect($measures)->chunk(1000)->each(function ($raws) use ($meter) {
            $raws = $raws->map(function ($raw) use ($meter) {
                return new \App\Models\Raw($meter['OperationID'], $meter['ID'], $meter['ConsoProd'], $meter['Timestep'], $meter['Unit'], $raw['t'], $raw['d']);
            })->toArray();
            dd($raws);
        });
```

When I don't use ->toArray(), I can see a collection of 1000 Raw elements:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2857 ▼
  #items: array:1000 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Raw {#1857 ▼
      #table: "raws"
      #casts: array:1 [ …1]
      +timestamps: array:1 [ …1]
      -operationId: "ACC00000001"
      -meterId: "30002431650000"
      -consoProd: "Conso"
      -timestep: "600000000000"
      -unit: "kW"
      -timestamp: "2018-09-11T00:00:00+02:00"
      -value: "7"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: false
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: []
      #original: []
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
    }
    1 => App\Models\Raw {#1858 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Raw {#1859 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\Raw {#1860 ▶}
```

But I try to convert it into an array with:

```
dd($raws->toArray());
```

I get:

```
array:1000 [
  0 => []
  1 => []
  2 => []
  3 => []
  4 => []
  5 => []
  6 => []
  7 => []
  8 => []
  9 => []...
```

Why ???

Comment: I think that it is because they are not preserved and conversion to array of unsaved entity had such behavior .. need to check it deeper for full answer

Comment: I could solve it thanks to your comment !

Comment: In my model, I had my field defined : `private string $operationId;` ...

Comment: I tried to change it to public, but it didn't work.

Comment: Removing them solved the problem. If you can explain it, I will accept your answer ! Thanks anyway !!!

Comment: Don't define them as attributes at the model Class Eloquent is making that automaticly ..
You have option to list Hidden and Visible attributes

Comment: yes, but shouldn't it be a good practice to define fields in a model ?

Comment: Not in Eloquent .. 
There are specific getters and setters that have additional logic added over that process. When you ask for $product->name it is not comming from a declared $name var but from a bag with attributes auto built on the table structure

Here is part of the info about it and why you shouldn't have them https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [Model.php](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/80538328f6e085e21a3f9a0aca350b0cf8be9290/Eloquent/Model.php#L166), in it's constructor it accepts an array of attributes and not multiple parameters. So you need to do the creation of `Raw.php` model like so.

```
$raws = $raws->map(function ($raw) use ($meter) {
    return new \App\Models\Raw([
        'operationId' => $meter['OperationID'],
        'meterId' => $meter['ID'],
        'consoProd' => $meter['ConsoProd'],
        'timestep' => $meter['Timestep'],
        'unit' => $meter['Unit'],
        'timestamp' => $meter['t'],
        'value' => $meter['d'],
    ]);
})->toArray();
```

It was a little hard to assume your database columns, the keys in the array, has to be the column name of the database so please check it.

Comment: As stated in the comments, i would not define the fields in the model.